# Moving from Java to PHP

Tags: java, php, development-environment

Recently I've made a move to PHP coding from the mobile Java world. In the past I also coded and tried to gather as much knowledge as possible about the Java EE platform. I got used to all the amazing possibilities of coding in Eclipse that now I can see I tend to miss or just don't know how to achieve such a fluency.

**Is there any good blog post, a tutorial, or maybe even a book on how to achieve the best possible toolset working with PHP?**

From what I've already learnt is this:

- use vim. It is indeed an amazing flow having fingers on the keyboard all the time
- when I want to find usages of a function, I grep
- I use ctags and the vim's plugin command tjump to go to method definitions

***Somehow though every time I switch from vim to the command line to grep something I feel slightly annoyed. It's like using search in Eclipse for the sake of figuring out a class hierarchy for instance.***

I believe there might be some of you who went through the same process and found good and well working solutions to things that Java engineers already take for granted that they're just there.

I know this is a very generic question, however my intention is to either get a link to an article describing all that I mentioned or just gather a lot of tips if that's the case with PHP (and it seems to me that this is the way it works generally at the moment - I hope that's not true).

**EDIT**: My current OS is Mac OS X, so cross platform solutions are preferred :-)

Comment: I use Notepad++. If I need to look up a function, I just hit Alt+F1 over it and the PHP docs open to the relevant page.

Comment: I would advise [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/projects/project.php?id=tools.pdt) for your IDE. Code completion for the win!

Comment: @Kolink - I Didn't know about that shortcut, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for recommending Notepad++. Happily I'm not stuck with Windows any more. Cross platform solutions like VIM or Eclipse are the way to go for me.

Comment: Is it just me, or do IDE's such as NetBeans, Eclipse etc just seem bloated?

Comment: I agree @Paul, that's why I'm trying to use vim and leverage the beauty of automating anything I need with bash scripts, group common tasks, perhaps write some vim macros when I get more familiar with it. That's the kind of knowledge a lot of PHP devs have, but I couldn't find it in one single place. Perhaps I'll write an article on this in a while if I get my knowledge organised better (also with answers from here) ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If you have done Java, then you have used Eclipse.

I would suggest you start with the Community Edition of [Zend Studio](http://www.zend.com/en/products/studio/downloads?src=downloadb). It is one of the best IDE's for PHP, personally. If you are more comfortable with the language, then use whatever, but start with something that will teach you, not make your life more difficult.

It is all the joys of Eclipse for Java, but for PHP. Function lookup, debugging, build profiles, SVN, FTP, and all the goodies in one!

If not, check out the PDT module for Eclipse. It is not as feature packed as Zend Studio, but gives you a great starting point.

Answer (score 0):

not familiar with PHP
But there are some [great ViM tips](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Best_Vim_Tips) you may need .